# Is there a clean way to maintain a contiguous background across empty CSS Grid cells?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In short, the markup I have is this:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<img>
<p></p>
<img>
<p></p>
```

For mobile, this is the exact ordering of content I need. However, on desktop, I want to pull the images out to a left column and have the text on a right column.

1) Currently I've implemented using CSS Grid (two columns with no rows defined). Is there a more elegant way to do this that is recommended?

2) I can't wrap my mind around how to have a background running down the right column (other than negative top and bottom margins for the paragraph blocks). Any suggestion?

Screenshot of what I have
[image]

[The mockup I'm trying to get to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEQBv.png) (in particular, the background in the right column)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution that I can show is not really clean.

It will mean creating selectors for as many **p** as you have, to force them to share a cell with the filler, that would hold the background.

I have used a neighbour selector, but you could go with some nth-child variant

```css
.container {
 border: solid 1px red;
 display: inline-grid;
 grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
}

p {
 background-color: lightgreen;
 grid-column: 2;
 grid-row: 2;
}

p ~ p {
 grid-row: 3;
}

.left {
 background-color: tomato;
 margin: 10px;
 grid-column: 1;
 height: 50px;
}


h1 {
 grid-column: 1 / span 2;
 grid-row: 1;
 border: solid 1px blue;
}

.filler {
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 100%;
 grid-row: 1 / span 25;
 grid-column: 2;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div class="left">IMAGE HERE</div>
<p>ppppppp</p>
<div class="left">IMAGE HERE</div>
<p>pp p p p p p </p>
<div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```